# Spring response ajax: 403 error

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am using Spring with java-config **AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer** instead of web.xml and my spring-controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String demo1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


    String poreqid = request.getParameter("poid");
    String refid = request.getParameter("refid");
    String status = request.getParameter("key");
    String key = poreqid+ refid+ status;
    return key;
    }
}
```

when I send post from jquery-ajax to spring controller, jquery shows error.
on jquery console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.206:8082/project1/demo1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have added

```
 @ComponentScan
 public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                                throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null &&  "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        // CORS "pre-flight" request
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  //            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  //            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");// 30 min
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

I have nothing changed rest of code,Please provide me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domains `localhost` and `192.168.1.206`are considered to be different origins, and you cant send ajax request from different origins without additional setup.

For enabling cross origin requests in Spring MVC you should add a filter that will explicitely allow request origins, by applying the proper headers in the response, an example of such a filter

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

and more reading on the topic you can find [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

You can remove the `@Component` and use the filter in a more traditional way, by declaring it in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.package.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I just added SimpleCORSFilter in my config files,
should I mention it into mainConfig file or else?

Comment: its a spring bean, so its enough to scan the package where the filter is placed. Alternatively, you can add it to web.xml, I've edited an answer

Comment: Still not working.
I used csrf in spring security, is that reason behind error?

Comment: Can you provide me a basic demo with jquery with spring security communication demo please.

Comment: Instead of `@ComponentScan` you should set the `@Component`. If it is still not working, post in the question the classes that bootstrap your configuration

Comment: Thank you. It was error because, spring cannot find filter file. I created bean for it and calls in context initializer. Now its working fine .